# Passing data to create view from store method in Laravel

Tags: laravel, jquery.repeater

I'm using a jquery repeater plugin and I need to post a json data which is repeater fields data to store method and back that data if there are validation errors. How that is possible?

Comment: have you try writing any code yet?

Answer (score 1):

Use laravel builtin validations and it will return you back with errors (if any).

```
public function store(Request $request){
    $validator  = Validator::make($request,[
       'name' => 'required',
       //...
     ]);
   if($validator->fails()){
   return response()->json(['errors' => $validator->errors()]);
   }
}
```

**jQuery Side**
  validate input on form submit

```
var name = $('#name').val();
if(name.length < -1){
   alert('name is required');
}
```

Comment: how about the jquery side? I think that is the OP's main issue although it's not specified in the question.